# adding commas to target multiple selectors stops properties from working

Tags: css

I have a little **CSS** block for my `input` placeholders, to set their `font-size` and `letter-spacing`. But for some reason, using commas for different selectors isn't working when it should.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
.lr__form-defaults > input[type="password"]::-webkit-input-placeholder, .lr__form-defaults > input[type="password"]::-moz-placeholder, .lr__form-defaults > input[type="password"]::-ms-input-placeholder{
    letter-spacing: initial;
    line-height: initial;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

And this doesn't work at all (on any browser). However, if I just do:

```
.lr__form-defaults > input[type="password"]::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    letter-spacing: initial;
    line-height: initial;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

It will work fine.

I have used commas to target multiple selectors beforehand, so I have no idea why this isn't working.

All help is appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vendor specific styles must be written separately.

If the browser sees one that it doesn't recognize, it will ignore the whole rule.

You have to write it as so:

```
.lr__form-defaults > input[type="password"]::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  letter-spacing: initial;
  line-height: initial;
  font-size: 14px;
} 

.lr__form-defaults > input[type="password"]::-moz-placeholder{
  letter-spacing: initial;
  line-height: initial;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

etc..

On the other hand, the properties can be written under the same rule:
For example:

```
.myclass {
  background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, yellow);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}
```

Comment: Well, that's a bit of a bummer :/ Thanks :)